# Unable to load msg [sensor_msgs/]

Tags: ros, rosmsg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when I use the instruction `rosmsg show sensor_msgs/` I get the following weird error:

`Unable to load msg [sensor_msgs/]: Cannot locate message [] in package [sensor_msgs] with paths [['/opt/ros/noetic/share/sensor_msgs/msg']]`

but when I type `ls /opt/ros/noetic/share/sensor_msgs/msg` I get the following output:

```
BatteryState.msg     Illuminance.msg       JoyFeedback.msg    MultiDOFJointState.msg  PointCloud.msg        Temperature.msg
CameraInfo.msg       Image.msg             Joy.msg            MultiEchoLaserScan.msg  PointField.msg        TimeReference.msg
ChannelFloat32.msg   Imu.msg               LaserEcho.msg      NavSatFix.msg           Range.msg
CompressedImage.msg  JointState.msg        LaserScan.msg      NavSatStatus.msg        RegionOfInterest.msg
FluidPressure.msg    JoyFeedbackArray.msg  MagneticField.msg  PointCloud2.msg         RelativeHumidity.msg
```

can you please tell me what is my mistake? thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/390273/unable-to-load-msg-%5Bsensor_msgs/%5D/) by [bhomaidan](https://answers.ros.org/users/71460/bhomaidan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 114 on 2021-11-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`rosmsg show` is intended to show you the contents of a single *message definition*, not the files inside a directory.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-11-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bhomaidan](https://answers.ros.org/users/71460/bhomaidan/) on 2021-11-07**:
@gvdhoorn True, I should hit `Tab` instead to see the messages inside as he did in the [Tutorial](https://learning.edx.org/course/course-v1:DelftX+ROS1x+1T2020/block-v1:DelftX+ROS1x+1T2020+type@sequential+block@7ff36759b3714aaea311e21e85f04ac0/block-v1:DelftX+ROS1x+1T2020+type@vertical+block@9e5b401803c64ab99027dbafbcc2d2d5)